# Data types limits and storage of address operations

Tags: c

I have two memory addresses under pointers. The first one is a begining of a string.

`char *beg`
The second is the end of the same string.

`char *end`
So length of the string is a distance between addresses:

`end - beg`

What is the difference between:

```
// 1.
if(end - beg > enother_string_end - enother_string_beg)
...
```

and

```
// 2.
unsigned long long int l1 = end - beg;
unsigned long long int l2 = enother_string_end - enother_string_beg;

if(l1 > l2)
...
```

Distance may be bigger than unsigned long long int, right? Does the first way solve problem with data type limit? How is a value stored for comparison in the first way?
Thanks

Comment: `beg - end` --> `end - beg` ?

Comment: Yeah, I think you have your subtractions flipped around.

Comment: Please use `size_t`.

Comment: Strictly you should use a ptrdiff_t. But size_t or even int is acceptable. It is unlikely that a string will be longer than the range of an int.

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` is only useful if `end` can come before `beg` *(well, the other way around in the example but I'll assume that's a mistake)*. Otherwise it introduces the risk of an overflow with no benefits.

Comment: sorry for mistake (end-beg is correct)